# BusinessHours.add() returning GMT instead of local

Tags: businesshours

I am testing `add()` method from [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_businesshours.htm#apex_System_BusinessHours_add) class and am getting an unexpected result.

As per documentation:

> Adds an interval of time from a start Datetime traversing business hours only. Returns the result Datetime in the **local time zone.**

Here's my test:

1. Start on Monday 2/12/24
2. Add 4 hours
3. Get a result of `2024-02-12 13:00:00`

Below are the Business Hours in my scratch org:

[image]

Here's the code I am executing:

```
Datetime startDt = Datetime.newInstance(2024, 2, 12, 9, 0, 0);

BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
 
System.debug('Result is ' + BusinessHours.add(bh.Id,startDt,(1*4)*60*60*1000));
```

Here's the debug log: `DEBUG|Result is 2024-02-12 21:00:00`

It's the result I am expecting but in GMT instead of local. If it was local it should have been 13:00 and not 21:00.

Next I tried `addGmt()` to see what that would return. As per documentation:

> Adds an interval of milliseconds from a start Datetime traversing business hours only. Returns the result **Datetime in GMT.**

```
Datetime startDt = Datetime.newInstance(2024, 2, 12, 9, 0, 0);

BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
 
system.debug('ResultGmt is ' + BusinessHours.addGmt(bh.Id,startDt,(1*4)*60*60*1000));
```

Debug statement: `DEBUG|ResultGmt is 2024-02-12 21:00:00`

I am getting the same result regardless if I use `add()` or `addGmt()`. Does anybody know why?

My user's timezone is the same as the org's timezone - (GMT-8:00).

Comment: Debug logs are always in UTC (aka GMT). You would need to explicitly format the datetime value in the user time zone to see it in debug logs in something other than UTC.

Comment: @PhilW Are you saying that if I store the result in a field I should see the actual local value for the `add()` method?

Comment: I suspect so, yes. Or otherwise show the value in the UI.

Comment: @PhilW Almost. It depends on the method you use.

Comment: @sfdcfox I did say explicitly format. I just didn't say `format`! ;)

Comment: @PhilW I think I need a nap, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system.debug('ResultGmt is ' + BusinessHours.addGmt(bh.Id,startDt,(1*4)*60*60*1000));
```

Calls `DateTime#toString`, which will always display in GMT. To verify this, try:

```
System.debug(DateTime.now().toString());
```

To get the correct, local time, use `DateTime#format`. You'll notice this gives the right time:

```
System.debug(DateTime.now().format());
```

So:

```
System.debug('Result is ' + 
  BusinessHours.add(bh.Id,startDt,(1*4)*60*60*1000).format()
);
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple but I missed it!